# AngularJS orderBy not working with trackBy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby, angularjs-track-by

I don't know why orderBy is not working with trackBy, it is making me crazy :(

Here is my HTML code:

```
        <div class="blocks-container" ng-init="loadProjects()" ng-controller="buildMonitorController">
<div class="row">
   <!-- <div> -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
             ng-if="!errorDialogActive"
             ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build track by build._id | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate' : true"
             ng-class="{'running': project.running ,'block-green': build._status ==='SUCCESS','block-red': build._status==='FAILURE'}"
             id="{{build._id}}">
            <div class="title-container"><p>{{build._buildTypeId}}</p></div>
            <div class="update-container col-xs-12">
            <time>{{ build.lastBuildDetails.startDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:s'}}</time>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--</div>-->

<!-- Start error state dialog -->
<div ng-include src="'views/main/error-dialog.html'"></div>
```

Everytime give me the same result even if i change the order to reverse

And Here my AngularJS code:

```
    $scope.refreshBuilds = function () {
    $scope.errorList.length = 0
    //@TODO remove this part right after the API is working
    //Init
    var suffix = '';
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);


    //simulate mock by random number
    switch (randomnumber) {

        case 1:
            suffix = '-success';
            break;

        case 2:
            suffix = '-less';
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    var url = 'mock/builds'+suffix+'.xml';
    console.log('url: ' + url)
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Basic AAA'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        //Recive builds from xml and reset scope
        var buildsToFilter = new X2JS().xml_str2json(data);
        $scope.errorDialogActive = false;
        //filter builds which have a no build API detail status
        if (buildsToFilter.builds.build !== undefined) {
            angular.forEach(buildsToFilter.builds.build, function (build, index) {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'mock/build-'+build._id+'.xml',
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: 'Basic AAA'
                    }
                }).success(function (buildDetailData) {
                    $scope.errorDialogActive = false;
                    //push detail data into build array
                    buildsToFilter.builds.build[index].lastBuildDetails = new X2JS().xml_str2json(buildDetailData).build;
                    console.log(buildsToFilter.builds.build[index]);

                }).error(function (data, status) {
                    $scope.errorDialogActive = true;
                    //remove build from index if no build detail was found
                    buildsToFilter.builds.build.splice(index, 1);
                    $scope.setError(status, '', '');
                }).then(function () {
                    //after filtering builds to display, setup builds $scope for FrontEnd
                    $scope.builds = buildsToFilter;
                });
            });
        } else {

        }

    }).error(function (data, status) {

        //active dialog if error happens & set error
        $scope.errorDialogActive = true;
        $scope.setError(status, 'builds', '');
    }).then(function () {

        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.finishedRequest = true; 
        }, 5000);


        //refresh right after proceed and a little delay
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log('Starting refresh');
            $scope.refreshBuilds();
        }, 21000);


    })
};
```

If You need more code please let me know

Comment: upload a sample fiddle or plunker so that we can make changes and update it and help you better.

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to make it works in plunker but it have to many external dependencies to work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the docs.  It doesn't appear you are using it correctly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

The last argument can only be "reverse".

Move 'track by build._id' to the end of the expression (after orderBy).

```
ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build track by build._id | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate'
```

Comment: Even if I chage it, it still disordered, Only works if i delete the trackBy but I need the trackBy :(

Comment: Yes if i put it like this : 
ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate' : reverse  track by build._id "

The animations stop working

Comment: without seeing code it is difficult to know what is going on with the animations. 

If you remove the reverse do the animations break?
Is it sorting properly with broken animations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74834/discussion-between-tpie-and-vistor).